# Actionscript 3.0: In what ways can the Kernel interact with objects in my application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, kernel

Im learning flash actionscript at a local college and have been asked to find out 3 ways how the kernel could interact with my application when creating an actionscript project. Ive done my research and looked through page after page online but cant seem to find some easy to understand answers to build my knowledge on.

Could anyone help?

**EDIT: Sorry the question was rather vague. The Kernel is a class that is being linked to the swf. Weve been asked to find out how the Kernel can effect and interact with the application.**

This is the class thats been created:

```
public class kernel extends MovieClip
    {
        public function kernel()
        {
            var ball1 = new myBall();  // creates an instance of the ball
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

            addChild(ball1); // adds the instance to the stage

        }
        private function update(e:Event)
        {
            ball1.update()
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kernel are we talking about?

Comment: Are you talking about a pixel bender kernel?

Comment: Sorry the question was rather vague. We have been creating actionscript application by using a Kernel class that is linked to the main SWF file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a Pixel Bender Kernel, I'm not quite sure there are 3 ways that these kernels can interact with your application. However, there are 2 very different ways that they can be used for sure. The first is that they can be applied a filter parameter to display ojects and the second is that you can directly pass raw data into a shader and run the job synchronously or asynchronously.

As such, Pixel Bender can be used for more than visual data manipulation, even just for doing raw asynchronous number crunching. If you can manage to come up with some sort of third application from this information, then all the power to you but to my knowledge these are the two distinct ways that you can use PB kernels in flash.

Links:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/pixel_bender_basics.html

https://www.adobe.com/ru/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_pixelbender.html